# CMake: cannot create target because another target with the same name already exists

Tags: cmake, pthreads

I'm trying to install plexe-sumo with cmake. I followed the tutorial at plexe.car2x.org and here's the results:

```
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo
-- 
-- Platform: 
--     Host: Linux4.15.0-34-genericx86_64
--     CMake: 3.12.2
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
-- 
-- Found Proj: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake:627 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "libsumo_swig_compilation" because
  another target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a
  custom target created in source directory
  "/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/src/libsumo".  See documentation for policy
  CMP0002 for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:39 (SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY)


-- Enabled features: Linux-4.15.0-34-generic Proj GUI GDAL OSG GL2PS SWIG
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

There is no file named 'libsumo_swig_compilation' under "/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/src/libsumo".

Then I checked the error log file, but the errors shown are about pthread saying 'undefined reference to pthread_creat' and 'cannot find -lpthreads'. Actually my pthread library is installed at 'libc6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0'.

So I was wondering what's the exact problem here and how to solve it. I'm using a virtual machine with ubuntu 16. I appreciate your help!

Following is the error log file:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_050d5/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -Wall -pedantic -Wextra    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:11: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type [-Wpedantic]
   return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
           ^
Linking C executable cmTC_050d5
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -Wall -pedantic -Wextra     -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_050d5 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_050d5.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'cmTC_050d5' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_050d5] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_050d5/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_050d5/fast] Error 2

File /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_9f654/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/local/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_9f654
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc  -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_9f654 -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_9f654.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f654' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_9f654] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cc/src/plexe-sumo/build-release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_9f654/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_9f654/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: According to the script [src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/michele-segata/plexe-sumo/blob/master/src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt), it creates SWIG library `libsumo` for Python, if Python libs are found, and for Java, if Java libraries are found. That is, if both Python and Java libraries are installed on your machine, `libsumo` library is created **twice**, and this is a real problem. Report that to the developers. (Log `CMakeOutput.txt` is unrelated here.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev This is probably not the cause since the python library is usually called _libsumo with an underscore unless that changed recently.

Comment: @Michael: Interesting. The function `SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(<name> ...)` actually creates a library target, named as `_<name>` for Python and `<name>` for other languages. But the function also creates a *CUSTOM* target which name doesn't depend on Python specific: it is always `<name>_swig_compilation`. And CMake complains exactly about this target. So it could be a bug in function `SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY`, which is a part of CMake distribution.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the cmake which comes with the distribution but build your own?

Comment: Thanks for all. The version of cmake coming with ubuntu 16 is too old, so I have to build my own...

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that this is really a behavior which only the new cmake shows. You could try to rename all references to libsumo in the java part of the CMakeLists.txt or simply use the CMakeLists of the main line sumo here: https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I didn't find anything related to Java in the CMakeLists.txt. I also tried to use the CMakeLists of sumo but it does not work...Should I try an older version of CMake?

Comment: Just replace libsumo by libsumojni in the section starting with if JAVA_FOUND in src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt,